# How come .parent() is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="apple">
    <div class="abc">
       <input id="go">
    </div>
</div>


$("#go").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.apple').hide(); // this doesn't work.
    $(this).parent().parent().hide(); //this works
});
```

I want the `.parent('.apple')` to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`jQuery.parent()` function](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) docs:

> [...] The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. [...]

In other words use `jQuery.parents()` instead of `jQuery.parent()`.

Comment: I was about to post this answer, but you beat me to it. You should probably add that `.parent(".selector")` is the same as `.parent().filter(".selector")`.

Answer (score 1):

The parent of the input is your div with class abc.  That's why it won't work.  You want to use *parents* plural to go up the parent chain:

> $("#go").click(function(){
>
> ```
> $(this).parents('.apple').hide();
> ```
>
> });

See this link for more info:  http://jqueryminute.com/jquery-parent-vs-parents/

Comment: I want JQuery to go up each parent and find the parent that matches "apple"

Comment: yup, you want to use "parents" plural for that, see my update.